# Calling Two Function on Click and return false

Tags: javascript

My code is this

```
<script>
 function a(){
  var num = $('#mobile_number).val();
  if !(isNAN(num)){
    alert("Integer")
    return false;
  }
 function b(){
  var addr = $('#addr).val();
  if(addr==""){
   return false;
  }
 }
}
</script>
<form>
 name:<input type="text" id="mobile_number"/>
 Address:<input type="text" id="addr"/>
 <input type="submit" onclick="a();return false;b();return false;"
</form>
```

but it submit value when i entered wrong input please explain me how can i call and return two function on a click and return if i entered wrong input thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to to `return false` if either one of `a` or `b` returns false.

The solution is to return the `logical and` value of `a()` and `b()`.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return a() && b()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
onclick="return a();"  

 function a(){
      var num = $('#mobile_number').val();
      if !(isNAN(num)){  
        alert("not a number");        
        return false;
      } 
      var addr = $('#addr').val();
      if(addr==""){
       alert("Address Empty");    
       return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate() {
    return a() && b();
}

onClick="validate();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form onSubmit="return a(); return b();">
    name:<input type="text" id="mobile_number"/>
    Address:<input type="text" id="addr"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

the return false within a and b will stop the form from submitting.

better yet .. make validation one function

```
<script>
    function validate() {
        var num = $('#mobile_number).val();
        if !(isNAN(num)){
            alert("Integer")
            return false;
        }
        var addr = $('#addr).val();
        if(addr==""){
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form onSubmit="return validate();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click on a submit button on a form, it will submit the form always. To call a js function on form submit, use OnSubmit in the form tag like

This way whenever the submit button is clicked, it will first call the two functions, and if things are find, then you can submit the form by using $("#form_id").submit().

Thank you

Comment: "Whenever you click on a submit button on a form, it will submit the form always."  No.

Answer (score 0):

[check here](http://jsbin.com/akebod/1/)

```
function a(){
  console.log("a");
}


function b(){
  console.log("b");
}


function callBoth(fn1, fn2) {
  fn1(); 
  fn2();

  return result; 
}

callBoth(a, b);
```